# Generic or specific repository when you need to support multiple ORM or sources?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, design-patterns, interface

I need to manipulate some data from a database via two different ways, Entity Framework and web service.

To simplify, lets say there are only two tables called A and B.

I am stuck on the design of this. Should I simply have two classes that derive from an interface that exposes the functions I want like so:

```
public interface IRepository
{
        bool AddA(A a);     
        bool RemoveA(A a);
        IEnumerable<A> GetAllA();
        bool AddB(B b);     
        bool RemoveB(B b);
        IEnumerable<B> GetAllB();
}

public class EfRepository : IRepository
{
        //actual code here
}

public class ServiceRepository : IRepository
{
        //actual code here
}
```

or should I try an approach which is more generic in nature:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
        bool Add(T t);
        bool Remove(T t);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        bool Update(T t);

}

public class EfARepository: IRepository<A>
{
        //actual code here

}

public class EfBRepository : IRepository<B>
{
        //actual code here
}

public class ServiceARepository: IRepository<A>
{
        //actual code here

}

public class ServiceBRepository : IRepository<B>
{
        //actual code here
}
```

The second approach seems cumbersome and repetitive since I am not really following the generic repository pattern because I'm not sure if its doable or worth the effort since Entity Framework already acts like a repository. Or would something like this be more sensible:

```
public class ARepository<Ef> : IRepository<A>
{
        //omitted
}
//or this
public class EfRepository<A> : IRepository<A>
{
        //omitted
}
```

But then again I can't wrap my head on injecting the context (Ef or service) into the classes and a repository of EF or vice versa doesn't really make much sense.

Please enlighten me and comment on the aforementioned designs and suggest a better approach or design for this scenario. Some examples in relation to this would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I use the following approach in several projects. The example is simplified a little bit.

```
/// <summary>
/// THE base class for all entities.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TKey">The type of the key for the entity.</typeparam>
public abstract class Entity<TKey>
{
  private TKey _id;

  public Entity() : this(default(TKey))
  {
  }

  public Entity(TKey id)
  {
    _id = id;
  }

  public Entity(Entity<TKey> source) : this(default(TKey))
  {
    if (source != null)
    {
      this._id = source._id;
    }
  }

  public TKey Id
  {
    get { return _id; }
    set { _id = value; }
  }

  public bool IsTransient()
  {
    return Id.Equals(default(TKey));
  }
}

public interface IRepository : IDisposable
{
  bool Exists();

  void OpenConnection(); // helper

  void CreateIfNotExists();  // helper

  IQueryable<T> GetAll<T, TKey>() where T : Entity<TKey>;

  IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding<T, TKey>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  IQueryable<T> SearchFor<T, TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  T GetById<T, TKey>(TKey id) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  void Add<T, TKey>(T entity) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  void Update<T, TKey>(T entity) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  void Delete<T, TKey>(T entity) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  void Delete<T, TKey>(TKey id) where T : Entity<TKey>;

  void Save();

  void Delete();
}
```

Then you derive all your entities from the `Entity<TKey>` base class and implement the repository.

```
public class MyRepository : IRepository
{
  private DbContext _context;

  public EFRepository(DbContext context)
  {
      if (context == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

      _context = context;
  }

  public bool Exists()
  {
    return _context.Database.Exists();
  }
  ...
  public IQueryable<T> GetAll<T, TKey>() where T : Entity<TKey>
  {
    return _context.Set<T>();
  }

  public IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding<T, TKey>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includeProperties) where T : Entity<TKey>
  {
    IQueryable<T> query = _context.Set<T>();

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties)
    {
      query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    return query;
  }

  public IQueryable<T> SearchFor<T, TKey>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : Entity<TKey>
  {
    return _context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
  }

  public T GetById<T, TKey>(TKey id) where T : Entity<TKey>
  {
    // use the static Equals method to accept null values
    return _context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => object.Equals(id, x.Id));
  }

  public void Add<T, TKey>(T entity) where T : Entity<TKey>
  {
    if (entity != null)
    {
      Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);  // new entity
    }
  }

  public void Update<T, TKey>(T entity) where T : Entity<TKey>
  {
    if (entity != null)
    {
      if (object.Equals(entity.Id, default(TKey)))
        Context.Set<T>().Add(entity);  // new entity
      else
        Context.Entry<T>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
  }
  public void Save()
  {
    Context.SaveChanges();
  }
  ...
  public void Dispose()
  {
    Dispose(true);
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing)
    {
      try
      {
        if (_context != null)
          _context.Dispose();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Debug.WriteLine("MyRepository.Dispose exception:" + ex);
      }
    }
  }
}

public class MyUser : Entity<int>
{
  public MyUser()
  {
    Name = null;
  }

  public MyUser(string user)
  { 
    Name = user;
  }

  public MyUser(MyUser source) : base(source)
  {
    if (source != null)
    {
      Name = Helpers.SafeCopy(source.Name);
    }
  }

  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```